# Is there an Python function could solve or support by manipulating many items in an array in the same time?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, data-manipulation

I have here an empty array and I need to change its items with my own items which I want to save them in. Please have a look over the code:

```
ans = np.empty(5, dtype=np.int64)    #here is the empty array which has 5   items
for i in range(4):                   # I have introduced here a for loop which 
                                     #goes over each item in that array
  a = 2                        #the first item I want to insert in that 
                               #array
  b = 4                        # the second one
  ans[i] =a  
  ans[i + 1] = b
  # I expected the following: [a, b, a, b, a] 
  # but it gives : [a, a, a, a, b]
```

I have tried the code which I provide you with:

```
ans = np.empty(5, dtype=np.int64)
for i in range(4):
    a = 2   
    b = 4 
    ans[i] =a
    ans[i + 1] = b
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Clarify: what you mean by "in the same time" ? Are you aware about functions `map`-`filter`-`reduce`? Functions of matrix manipulation in module `numpy` that you use in your code? Are they "in the same time" or not?

Comment: Please explain: a) why `np.empty(5)` if you need just 4 elements?, b) why not just `np.array([2,4,2,4], np.int64)`? Why do you need loops?

Comment: 5 was just wrong I mean 4, sorry about that. in the same time I mean with, that I change the elements only in one for loop, actually I tried with two for loops and it was working but my lecturer did not accept it. The problem is that we have the Excel files which consist of a big number of data and what I mean actually with a and b is that they are very big lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a logical problem in your code. in *i<sup>th</sup>* iteration you are accessing *i+1<sup>th</sup>* element and *i+1<sup>th</sup>* element and in the *i+1<sup>th</sup>* iterationyou are modifying *i<sup>th</sup>* element which was *i+1<sup>th</sup>* element for *i<sup>th</sup>* iteration. Hence always current element will be in array means ans[i]=2 will work till 3.
To do what you are trying to do, you have to increment the value of loop variable by 2.

```
ans = np.empty(5, dtype=np.int64)
for i in range(0,5,2):    #incrementing with 2 so that you do not overwrite the previous element
a = 2   
b = 4 
ans[i] = a
if i+1<5:     # This is used to check in case you are accessing out of range element
    ans[i + 1] = b
# This will output to 2 4 2 4 2
```

Python range() syntax is range([start], stop[, step])

I think this will help you to get where you are going wrong..